# How can ignore part of a line in a file with c++?

Tags: c++, file

In the code below, you can see a self compiler thing I tried to/am still making. I'm wondering at the 2nd `while` loop (`while(numOfLines <=line) {...}`), how could I run the code there? The comments are either what the code does, or a question with the code that needs to be answered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Life {
  public:
    void compile() {
      //Get the main files content and store into a var...
      string txt;
      int line;
      //The file I want to get
      ifstream file("index.txt");
      string fileCont;
      int numOfLines = 0;
      //Get the lines of the file
      while(getline (file, txt)) {
        line++;
      }
      //After that make a statment to get the #of lines to create a compile statment
      while(numOfLines <= line) {
        
        getline(file, txt);
        if(txt.rfind("say")) {
          //How can I ignore the say part and get the content inside the parentheses?
          //Ex: say("Hello World");
          //How could I store the content inside of the parentheses to a variable?
          cout <<"say command found" <<endl;
          txt.ignore("say");
          to_string(txt);
        }
        numOfLines++;
        
      }
      
    }
};
```

Comment: Depends on your needs.  You could do something as simple as checking matching criteria, as you are doing.  Or use a [regular expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), if the format is amenable to checking for a regular expression.  Or something as fancy as creating a grammar and parser using something like Boost [Spirit X3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html).

Comment: After you count all the lines in the file, you need to clear the EOF flag and rewind before you read from the file again.

Answer (score 0):

If you present a simplified version of algorithm and you really need the lines count, please consider reopening 'file' or move the file pointer to the beginning of the file : file::seekg( 0 )

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified code fragment for parsing a file, per my understanding of your requirements:

```
std::string text;
while (std::getline(file, text))
{
    std::string::size_type  found_position = 0U;
    found_position = text.find("say(");
    if (found_position != std::npos)
    {
        Validate_Text(text);
    }
}
```

The `Validate_Text` function will validate the given text and perform operations on the text.

Comment: Uh there's an error with Validate_Text... Not sure if I'm stupid or anything but it's is the morning for me and I just woke up so...

Comment: @AyE:  I'm a little stressed right now, so my mind reading skills are not sharp.  What's the error with `Validate_Text()`?